# Añadir un texto entre index de un ciclo FOR que imprime lista

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for

mi codigo intenta imprimir los asientos de un avión, la lista debería verse así:  [image: Ejemplo]

Solo logro imprimir la lista completa sin poder separar con"----" los asientos del 31 al 42 que son asientos vip. Solo se que debo hacerlo en el ciclo for pero no encuentro una solución. debo hacerlo todo con una sola lista. Gracias

aquí mi codigo:

```
Asientos = [
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        ]

contador=1
for fila in range(7):
    for columna in range(6):
        Asientos[fila][columna] = contador
        contador = contador + 1
print("\n\t\tASIENTOS:\n")
for fila in range(7):
    print (f"|\t{Asientos[fila][0]}\t{Asientos[fila][1]}\t{Asientos[fila]    [2]}\t\t{Asientos[fila][3]}\t{Asientos[fila][4]}\t{Asientos[fila][5]}\t|")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es definir el primer asiento `vip` por ejemplo: `primer_asiento_vip = 31` y luego en tu ciclo dónde imprimes preguntar si estamos en la fila dónde comienza el `vip`:

```
if primer_asiento_vip == ((fila * columnas) + 1):
      print("|   ----------      ----------- |")
```

Resumiendo y ajustando algunas cosas de tu código:

```
filas = 7
columnas = 6
primer_asiento_vip = 31
data = list(range(1, (filas * columnas) + 1))
Asientos = [data[i:i+columnas] for i in range(0, len(data), columnas)]


print("\n\t\tASIENTOS:\n")
for fila in range(7):
    if primer_asiento_vip == ((fila * columnas) + 1):
      print("|   ----------      ----------- |")
    print (f"|\t{Asientos[fila][0]}\t{Asientos[fila][1]}\t{Asientos[fila]    [2]}\t\t{Asientos[fila][3]}\t{Asientos[fila][4]}\t{Asientos[fila][5]}\t|")


        ASIENTOS:

|   1   2   3       4   5   6   |
|   7   8   9       10  11  12  |
|   13  14  15      16  17  18  |
|   19  20  21      22  23  24  |
|   25  26  27      28  29  30  |
|   ----------      ----------- |
|   31  32  33      34  35  36  |
|   37  38  39      40  41  42  |
```

Comentarios:

- Simplifiqué un poco tu generación de la matriz
- Generamos un lista de número de 1 a filas * columnas
- Y vamos "particionado" esta lista por fila para terminar con la matriz de `Asientos`

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes insertar un `if fila == 5:`. De ese modo, la acción se realizara sólo al procesar la línea 5.

```
Asientos = [
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        ]

contador=1
for fila in range(7):
    for columna in range(6):
        Asientos[fila][columna] = contador
        contador = contador + 1
print("\n\t\tASIENTOS:\n")
for fila in range(7):
    if fila == 5:
        print("------------ -------")
        
    print (f"|\t{Asientos[fila][0]}\t{Asientos[fila][1]}\t{Asientos[fila][2]}\t\t{Asientos[fila][3]}\t{Asientos[fila][4]}\t{Asientos[fila][5]}\t|")
```